# Slow execution of Java Code that reads and updates Excel(xlsx) file

Tags: java, excel, xlsx

I wrote this program that goes through every line and try to find particular data and then based on that, find the specific xml file and extract the data and upload it on the excel sheet. The excel sheet is about 90,000 lines so I can understand why the code maybe slow. But it seems to be too slow, it updates about 5000 lines in 1 hour, and for 90,000 lines; it will take forever. 
I uploaded xml beans and gave -Xmx to be 2048m, so its not a memory issue. When I changed the parameter to be 1 to 100, it did updated; so I know for sure that the code is working, but its just too slow. 
Any suggestions?

```
    import java.util.*;

    import java.io.*;

    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class XMLRead {

public static void main(String[] Args) throws Exception{




    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Desktop/TestECG.xlsx"));
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook (fis);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("ecg");

    for (int i = 1; i <= 91332; i++){ 

        if(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(2) == sheet.getRow(i-1).getCell(2) && sheet.getRow(i).getCell(15) == sheet.getRow(i-1).getCell(15) && sheet.getRow(i).getCell(16) == sheet.getRow(i-1).getCell(16)) {
            XSSFCell lame = sheet.getRow(i-1).getCell(19);
            String lamer = lame.toString();
            sheet.getRow(i).getCell(19).setCellValue(lamer);

        }

        else{

            XSSFCell TimeCell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(16);
            String TimeString = TimeCell.toString();
            String gettime[] = TimeString.split(":");
            String TimeHour = gettime[0];
            String TimeMinute = gettime[1];
            String TimeSecond = gettime[2];
            XSSFCell DateCell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(15);
            String DateString = DateCell.toString();
            String DateYear = DateString.substring(5, 9);
            String TempDateMonth = DateString.substring(2,5);
            String DateMonth = "";
            if (TempDateMonth.equals("Jan")){ 

                DateMonth = "01";
            }
            else if (TempDateMonth.equals("Feb")){ 

                DateMonth = "02";
            }
            else if (TempDateMonth.equals("Mar")){ 

                DateMonth = "03";
            }
            else if (TempDateMonth.equals("Apr")){ 

                DateMonth = "04";
            }
            else if (TempDateMonth.equals("May")){ 

                DateMonth = "05";
            }
            else if (TempDateMonth.equals("Jun")){ 

                DateMonth = "06";
            }
            else if (TempDateMonth.equals("Jul")){ 

                DateMonth = "07";
            }
            else if (TempDateMonth.equals("Aug")){ 

                DateMonth = "08";
            }
            else if (TempDateMonth.equals("Sep")){ 

                DateMonth = "09";
            }
            else if (TempDateMonth.equals("Oct")){ 

                DateMonth = "10";
            }
            else if (TempDateMonth.equals("Nov")){ 

                DateMonth = "11";
            }
            else if (TempDateMonth.equals("Dec")){ 

                DateMonth = "12";
            }

            String DateDay = "";
            String TempDateDay = DateString.substring(0, 2);
            if (Integer.parseInt(TempDateDay.trim())< 10){

                DateDay = "0" + TempDateDay;
            }

            else if (Integer.parseInt(TempDateDay.trim()) >= 10){

                DateDay = TempDateDay;
            }

            String CombineLowValue = DateYear + DateMonth + DateDay + TimeHour + TimeMinute + TimeSecond;

            XSSFCell SubjIDCell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(2);
            String SUBID = SubjIDCell.toString();

            File ECGDirectory = new File("C:/Users/ahmeda/Documents/ECG/");

            String[] names = ECGDirectory.list();

            String RightXML = null;
            String getTheName = null;

            searchloop: for(String name: names){ 

                if (new File("C:/Documents/ECG/" + name).isDirectory())
                    {

                        RightXML = ListFiles("C:/Documents/ECG/" + name + "/",SUBID, CombineLowValue);
                        if (RightXML != null){ 

                            getTheName = name;
                            break searchloop;
                        }
                 }


            }

            if(getTheName != null && RightXML != null){ 


                File readXMLfile = new File("C:/Users/ahmeda/Documents/ECG/" + getTheName + "/" + RightXML);
                Scanner read = new Scanner(readXMLfile);
                int onlyoneIDroot = 0; 
                int onlyonelowvalue = 0;
                int onlyoneidextension = 0;
                String searchidroot = "id root";
                String searchlowvalue = "low value";
                String searchidextension = "id extension";
                while (read.hasNextLine()){
                    String readline = read.nextLine();

                    if (readline.indexOf(searchidroot.toLowerCase()) != -1 && onlyoneIDroot != 1){ 

                        String getid[] = readline.split("=");
                        String almost[] = getid[1].split("\"");
                        searchidroot = almost[1];
                        onlyoneIDroot++;
                    }
                    else if (readline.indexOf(searchlowvalue.toLowerCase()) != -1  && onlyonelowvalue != 1){ 

                        String getid[] = readline.split("=");
                        String almost[] = getid[1].split("\"");
                        searchlowvalue = almost[1];
                        onlyonelowvalue++;
                    }
                    else if (readline.indexOf(searchidextension.toLowerCase()) != -1  && onlyoneidextension != 1){ 

                        String getid[] = readline.split("=");
                        String almost[] = getid[1].split("\"");
                        searchidextension = almost[1];
                        onlyoneidextension++;
                    }



                }

                if(SUBID.equals(searchidextension) && CombineLowValue.equals(searchlowvalue)){

                    sheet.getRow(i).getCell(19).setCellValue(searchidroot);

                    System.out.println("I am right here, just to see if this is even working.");

                }
                read.close();
            }
        }

    }

    fis.close();
    FileOutputStream fos =new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/Users/ahmeda/Desktop/TestECG.xlsx"));
        workbook.write(fos);
        workbook.close();
        fos.close();
    System.out.println("Done"); 

}

static String ListFiles(String file, String ID, String LowValue) {

  String files = null;
  File folder = new File(file);
  File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 
  //int x = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {

   if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {

       String getDate[] = listOfFiles[i].getName().split("_");
       String getID = getDate[2].substring(0,4);
       //System.out.println(listOfFiles[i].getName().split("_"));
       //System.out.println(getDate[2]);
       /*System.out.println(getID);
       System.out.println(ID);
       System.out.println(getDate[3]);
       System.out.println(LowValue);*/

       if(getID.equals(ID) && getDate[3].equals(LowValue)){ 

           files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
           //System.out.println(files);
           return files;

       }



      }
  }
return files;
}
```

}

Comment: Most likely you are performing an operation which is really expensive.  I suggest you use a profiler to work out where the time is being spent as if anyone was to guess it would most likely be wrong.  Could you not important the data via CSV as you should be able to do all 90K lines in about a second.